# SQL Update one item at a time in order

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have this c# code that does an SQL Update that could be doing multiple updates at a time. Now the table I am updating has a column called SortOrder, so while I am doing these multiple updates, I would like to do the updates in order of the sortOrder column...is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
public void PostScheduledTasks(List<CellModel> cells)
        {
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    @"UPDATE ScheduleTasks_Copy  
                      SET 
                          ActualStart=@actualStart,
                          ActualFinish=@actualFinish,
                          ActualEndDate=@actualEndDate,
                          UserDate1=@userDateOne,
                          IsCompleted=@isCompleted
                      WHERE ScheduleTaskID = @scheduleTaskID");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@isCompleted", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userDateOne", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualStart", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualFinish", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualEndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@scheduleTaskID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);


                cmd.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@isCompleted"].Value = cmd.Parameters["@percentComplete"].Value = (cells[i].selected == true) ? 1 : 0;
                    cmd.Parameters["@userDateOne"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].scheduledDate) ? cells[i].scheduledDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@actualStart"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].actualDate) ? cells[i].actualDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@actualFinish"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@actualEndDate"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@scheduleTaskID"].Value = cells[i].scheduleTaskID;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception, and can you try adding parameters inside the loop and in the start of loop have `cmd.Paramaters.Clear();`

Comment: I am not getting any errors, this code works fine, I am just looking to add code that will update them by the column sortOrder

Comment: This means that you have to order your `List<CellModel> cells` by `sortOrder` first...

Comment: How about using a cursor to update the rows?

Comment: A few questions: 1) Why are you setting the parameter `@percentComplete` (as part of setting `@isCompleted`) when it is not part of the query, 2) why do you want to update them in order if it is currently working as is, 3) how many records are you updating per operation (i.e. how many calls does this currently make), 4) would it suffice, if not too large of a set, to update them all at the same time, 5) what is the schema of this table (meaning, is there more than 1 record per scheduleTaskID)?

Comment: Is SortOrder available to read from the source data (the "cells" array/object) or is that *only* in the database?  I'm asking because every other data point can be found within "cells[i]".

Comment: What is the purpose of this odd and normally unnecessary condition?  Why would you need to do the Updates one at a time?  And then, why in this order?  Whatever you are trying to do there's probably a better way to acheive it in SQL than this very non-set oriented condition.

Comment: Following up on @RBarryYoung 's comment... the order in which rows are updated or inserted in SQL Server has zero impact on subsequent SELECT queries.  The order in does not affect the order out.  Expecting that it might, or usually does, is dangerous.

Comment: I have to concur with @RBarryYoung. Even the best answer given here will easily be outperformed by a set-based solution where you 'simply' push the new data in a temporary table and update the destination table in a single operation. Unless you have some good (and exotic) reason to do them one-by-one (##), **going for a set-based solution really is the way to go**.
(##: triggers are NOT a good reason as those too benefit from set-based approaches over row-by-row approaches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **If "SortOrder" can be ascertained from the source object "cells", like other attributes:**

Then the most efficient way would be to sort "cells" by SortOrder prior to iterating.  The exact method to do so is beyond the scope of the question, since you have not told us what "cells" is, exactly (a list? an array? a custom object? a set?)

### **If SortOrder can only be ascertained by querying the database:**

Then, not surprisingly, you'll need to query the database:

```
SELECT ScheduleTaskID, SortOrder FROM ScheduleTasks_Copy ORDER BY SortOrder
```

You iterate through that rowset, grabbing the `ScheduleTaskID` each time.  For each `ScheduleTaskID`, iterate through "cells" until you find the matching task (`cells[i].scheduleTaskID == TaskID`), and THEN do the database update using the matching task from the source table.

Here is very rough code, I haven't written C# in a while:

```
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ScheduleTaskID, SortOrder FROM ScheduleTasks_Copy ORDER BY SortOrder;", connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int taskid = reader.GetInt32(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
            {
             if (cells[i].scheduleTaskID == taskid) {
                 cmd.Parameters["@isCompleted"].Value = cmd.Parameters["@percentComplete"].Value = (cells[i].selected == true) ? 1 : 0;
                 cmd.Parameters["@userDateOne"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].scheduledDate) ? cells[i].scheduledDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                 cmd.Parameters["@actualStart"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].actualDate) ? cells[i].actualDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                 cmd.Parameters["@actualFinish"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                 cmd.Parameters["@actualEndDate"].Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
                 cmd.Parameters["@scheduleTaskID"].Value = cells[i].scheduleTaskID;
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step back and ignoring your actual question about running the updates concurrently, lets assume that your problem isn't "can I run a bunch of single updates concurrently?" and instead its "how do I update each of the items in my `List<CellModel> cells` as quickly/efficiently as possible?".

Obviously, running single updates sequentially doesn't work when `cells.Count` gets large, likely due to the fact that the cost of performing the update is dwarfed by the overheads incurred in performing multiple roundtrips across the network. It follows that running a bunch of single updates concurrently probably isn't the most efficient solution either.

Instead, lets move the whole `cells` list in one go.  This means the server has everything it needs to process our request. If `cells.Count` is large, SqlBulkCopy (as suggested by [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598182/8262)) will be hard to beat. Alternatively, a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) could work fine for smaller sets.

Once the data is available to the server, all you need to do is perform a single update joining against the temp table/variable and you're done ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#OtherTables) has some good examples of this technique.)  Do note, however, that if `cells` contains duplicate scheduleTaskID you may also have to perform a little extra pre-processing (ensuring that the highest sortOrder wins, etc.)

Example:

```
create table #temp(scheduleTaskID int, isCompleted bit, userDateOne datetime, actualStart datetime, actualFinish datetime, actualEndDate datetime)

--populate #temp via SqlBulkCopy, etc

update st
set st.ActualStart = t.actualStart
  , st.ActualFinish = t.actualFinish
  , st.ActualEndDate = t.actualEndDate
  , st.UserDate1 = t.userDateOne
  , st.IsCompleted = t.isCompleted
from dbo.ScheduleTasks_Copy st
     inner join #temp t on st.ScheduleTaskID = t.scheduleTaskID

drop table #temp
```

The join syntax for updates isn't as well known as it probably should be - it becomes ridiculously useful once you get used to the slight awkwardness...

Answer (score 1):

You would have to grab the values of the SortOrder column initially, and then iterate through them updating with SortOrder = X in the WHERE clause:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
```

Fill dt from query like: SELECT SortOrder FROM ScheduleTasks_Copy

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(
        @"UPDATE ScheduleTasks_Copy  
        SET 
        ActualStart=@actualStart,
        ActualFinish=@actualFinish,
        ActualEndDate=@actualEndDate,
        UserDate1=@userDateOne,
        IsCompleted=@isCompleted
        WHERE ScheduleTaskID = @scheduleTaskID
        AND SortOrder = @sortOrder");

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@isCompleted", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userDateOne", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualStart", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualFinish", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@actualEndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@scheduleTaskID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sortOrder", dr["SortOrder"].ToString());
}
```

(I've not tested this code for syntax, but it gets across the general idea)

Though I guess it depends on the reason you want to do this, there seems to me a limited number of reasons that this would be required.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `CellModel` has the `sortOrder` property? Because it should. And in this case you can add this line:

```
cells = cells.OrderBy(o => o.sortOrder); // add this -> order your cells first
for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++) { 
...
}
```

If you don't have the `sortOrder` property you should find another way to sort this collection.

Another solution would be to get the `ScheduleTaskID`'s that you expect to update ordered by `sortOrder` using:

```
 select ScheduleTaskID from ScheduleTasks_Copy order by SortOrder
```

Then you should go through all these items and if you find an item in `cells` having the same `ScheduleTaskID` then you should do the update.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you could do is upload your result into a temp table, then use a cursor server side to roll through and update all your rows in the specified order. This would probably be easier if you are able to use sql user defined types and stored procedures.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table ##Tasks(id int, isCompleted bit, userDateOne datetime, actualStart datetime, actualFinish datetime, actualEndDate datetime)", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable localTempTable = new DataTable("Tasks");
localTempTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
localTempTable.Columns.Add("isCompleted", typeof(bool));
localTempTable.Columns.Add("userDateOne", typeof(DateTime));
localTempTable.Columns.Add("actualStart", typeof(DateTime));
localTempTable.Columns.Add("actualFinish", typeof(DateTime));
localTempTable.Columns.Add("actualEndDate", typeof(DateTime));

for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    var row = localTempTable.NewRow();
    row["id"] = cells[i].scheduleTaskID;
    row["isCompleted"] = (cells[i].selected == true);
    row["userDateOne"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].scheduledDate) ? cells[i].scheduledDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
    row["actualStart"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].actualDate) ? cells[i].actualDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
    row["actualFinish"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
    row["actualEndDate"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cells[i].finishedDate) ? cells[i].finishedDate : (object)DBNull.Value;
}

localTempTable.AcceptChanges();

using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##Tasks";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(localTempTable);
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    declare orderedUpdate cursor 
    for 
    select tempTasks.* from ##tasks tempTasks
    inner join ScheduleTasks tasks on tempTasks.id =  tasks.ScheduleTaskID
    order by tasks.sortOrder;

declare @id int, @isCompleted bit, @actualStart datetime, @actualFinish datetime, @actualEndDate datetime, @userDateOne datetime;

open orderedUpdate;
fetch next from orderedUpdate INTO @id, @isCompleted, @userDateOne, @actualStart, @actualFinish, @actualEndDate 
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
    UPDATE ScheduleTasks_Copy  
        SET 
            ActualStart=@actualStart,
            ActualFinish=@actualFinish,
            ActualEndDate=@actualEndDate,
            UserDate1=@userDateOne,
            IsCompleted=@isCompleted
        WHERE ScheduleTaskID = @id;
end
close orderedUpdate
deallocate orderedUpdate", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is still unclear as to *why* there is a desire to update the set of records in any particular order (is there a trigger that causes some down-stream effect that would benefit from being processed in the order of the `sortOrder` field?), it should be pointed out that doing all of the updates in a single `UPDATE` statement renders the ordering irrelevant. It has been pointed out by a few others already that taking a set-based approach will be much faster (and it certainly will be), but being done in a single UPDATE means that transactionally there was no order (on a practical level).

Making this set-based via `SqlBulkCopy` has already been mentioned, but my preference is for using Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs) as they allow for streaming the `Cells` collection straight to the stored procedure that will do the UPDATE (well, technically via [tempdb], but close enough). Conversely, using `SqlBulkCopy` means needing to make a copy of the existing `Cells` collection in the form of a `DataTable.

Below is both the T-SQL and C# code for converting the existing process to using a TVP. It should be noted that if there is still some reason for doing this in a particular order, the only thing to change would be how the table variable in the stored procedure is handled.

### T-SQL code

```sql
-- First: You need a User-Defined Table Type
CREATE TYPE dbo.ScheduleTasksImport AS TABLE
(
   ScheduleTaskID INT NOT NULL, -- optionally mark this field as PRIMARY KEY
   IsCompleted BIT NOT NULL,
   ActualStart DATETIME NULL,
   ActualFinish DATETIME NULL,
   ActualEndDate DATETIME NULL,
   UserDate1 DATETIME NULL
);
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[ScheduleTasksImport] TO [user_or_role];
GO

-- Second: Use the UDTT as an input param to an import proc.
--         Hence "Tabled-Valued Parameter" (TVP)
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImportData (
   @ImportTable    dbo.ScheduleTasksImport READONLY
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE stc
SET    stc.ActualStart = imp.ActualStart,
       stc.ActualFinish = imp.ActualFinish,
       stc.ActualEndDate = imp.ActualEndDate,
       stc.UserDate1 = imp.UserDate1,
       stc.IsCompleted = imp.IsCompleted
FROM ScheduleTasks_Copy stc
INNER JOIN @ImportTable imp
        ON imp.ScheduleTaskID = stc.ScheduleTaskID
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.ImportData TO [user_or_role];
```

### C# code

Part 1: Define the method that will take the collection and return it as `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRows(List<CellModel> Cells)
{
   SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[] {
      new SqlMetaData("ScheduleTaskID", SqlDbType.Int),
      new SqlMetaData("IsCompleted", SqlDbType.Bit),
      new SqlMetaData("ActualStart", SqlDbType.DateTime),
      new SqlMetaData("ActualFinish", SqlDbType.DateTime),
      new SqlMetaData("ActualEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime),
      new SqlMetaData("UserDate1", SqlDbType.DateTime)
   };

   SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);

   // read a row, send a row
   for (int _Index = 0; _Index < Cells.Count; _Index++)
   {
      // Unlike BCP and BULK INSERT, you have the option here to create an
      // object, do manipulation(s) / validation(s) on the object, then pass
      // the object to the DB or discard via "continue" if invalid.
      _DataRecord.SetInt32(0, Cells[_Index].scheduleTaskID);
      _DataRecord.SetBoolean(1, Cells[_Index].selected); // IsCompleted
      _DataRecord.SetDatetime(2, Cells[_Index].actualDate); // ActualStart
      _DataRecord.SetDatetime(3, Cells[_Index].finishedDate); // ActualFinish
      _DataRecord.SetDatetime(4, Cells[_Index].finishedDate); // ActualEndDate
      _DataRecord.SetDatetime(5, Cells[_Index].scheduledDate); // UserDate1

      yield return _DataRecord;
   }
}
```

Part 2: Replace your current `PostScheduledTasks` method with the following that just executes the `ImportData` stored procedure. When the stored procedure is executed, it will ask for the value of the `@ImportTable` input parameter which will start the process of streaming the records across.

```
public static void PostScheduledTasks(List<CellModel> Cells)
{
   SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand("ImportData", _Connection);
   _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlParameter _TVParam = new SqlParameter();
   _TVParam.ParameterName = "@ImportTable";
   _TVParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   _TVParam.Value = SendRows(Cells); // method return value is streamed data
   _Command.Parameters.Add(_TVParam);

   try
   {
      _Connection.Open();

      // Send the data and process the UPDATE
      _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   finally
   {
      _Connection.Close();
   }

   return;
}
```

Please note that the two C# listing really go in the same file but were broken apart here for readability. If they are put into separate `.cs` files, then the `using` statements will need to be copied over for the second listing.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the obvious question about why you would want to do this, you can try this hack:
Insert the data into a temp table (using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), then use a MERGE with an ORDER BY clause in the source.  In this example I'm using ScheduleTasks_Copy as the "temp" table and ScheduleTasks as the destination.

```
MERGE ScheduleTasks AS T
USING (SELECT TOP 99999999 C.* 
       FROM ScheduleTasks_Copy C
       JOIN ScheduleTasks S
         ON C.ID = S.ID
       ORDER BY S.SortOrder ASC) AS S
ON S.ID = T.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET T.ActualStart = S.ActualStart,
      T.ActualFinish = S.ActualFinish,
      T.ActualEndDate = S.ActualEndDate,
      T.UserDate1 = S.UserDate1,
      T.IsCompleted = S.IsCompleted,
      T.UpdatedOn =  dbo.GetDateValue();
```

Don't worry about the silly GetDateValue function and UpdatedOn column.  I just included them so that you could see in which order the updates were performed.  If you want to update the records in reverse order, just change the sort order to DESC.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbc5f/16

Personally I suggest avoid things like this and redesigning your solution so that it avoids the issue altogether.